# What is the meaning of 'playing hard to get'?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, expressions

Today I heard the phrase 'playing hard to get'.

What is its meaning?

Is this phrase commonly used in English speaking countries?

Comment: -1 search: ['playing hard to get define'](https://www.google.com/search?q=playing+hard+to+get+define)

Comment: Or [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-play-hard-to-get).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often in romantic relationships, this is where someone may make it difficult for the other person to pursue a relationship by having limited availability, being mean or a few other factors that make having the relationship a challenging goal.

It is a commonly used phrase in some circles. In March 2014, a magazine called "Psychology Today" had an article on [When Should You Play Hard to Get?](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-attraction-doctor/201403/when-should-you-play-hard-get) as an example of its use.

Answer (score 11):

Being "*hard to get*" is the idea of not displaying interest when you have it. The end goal of this action is to increase the affection the opposing side displays and/or has for you.

It is often used in romantic pursuits:

> "*She's playing hard to get!*" - would translate to - "*She likes me, she just doesn't want to show it*".

Keep in mind, that it can be used by native speakers in any context that linguistics allow it:

> "*How did the meeting go*?", "*They are playing hard to get, but they have no other choice than to accept our terms.*" - would mean - "*They are pretending not to be interested so we can make them a better offer, but they...*"

However, it is important to note that the term is commonly used by the *receiving* side of the said action. This means the side that is "*hard to get*" may not have any **actual interest** in said person, or object, at all but for various reasons such as ego, clouded judgement, misunderstanding and/or others, is falsely alleged to.

> "*I asked her out and tried to kiss her but she's playing hard to get*" - whereas **her** thoughs might be - "*I barely even know him, why would he do that?*" 
>   implying she has no interest in him, despite his beliefs.

Source: My surroundings and experience.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of this phrase is:

> To ​pretend that you are less ​interested in someone than you really
>   are as a way of making them more ​interested in you, ​especially at
>   the ​start of a ​romantic ​relationship
>
> Example: Why won't you ​call him back? Are you ​playing hard to get?

Quoted verbatim from [Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary.](https://books.google.com/books?id=PDHCFSRmjSMC&pg=PA1083&lpg=PA1083&dq=pretend%20that%20you%20are%20less%20%E2%80%8Binterested%20in%20someone%20than%20you%20really%20are%20as%20a%20way%20of%20making%20them%20more%20%E2%80%8Binterested%20in%20you,%20%E2%80%8Bespecially%20at%20the%20%E2%80%8Bstart%20of%20a%20%E2%80%8Bromantic%20%E2%80%8Brelationship&source=bl&ots=6rzOkCd_0Z&sig=jmyOhuK6wviIUbTDh1fONbcwFc8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSpLLL4IXPAhUBZj4KHRubCjkQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=pretend%20that%20you%20are%20less%20%E2%80%8Binterested%20in%20someone%20than%20you%20really%20are%20as%20a%20way%20of%20making%20them%20more%20%E2%80%8Binterested%20in%20you%2C%20%E2%80%8Bespecially%20at%20the%20%E2%80%8Bstart%20of%20a%20%E2%80%8Bromantic%20%E2%80%8Brelationship&f=false)